# Подскажите путь к решению задачки на Питоне

Tags: python

Начал учить Python и застрял на этой задачке (уже больше недели). Пожалуйста, подскажите путь к решению, у меня идей нет…

Задача:

Вам необходимо создать программу, которая выводит состояние магазина Open или Closed в зависимости от времени и дня недели.

Магазин открыт ежедневно с 10 до 21, кроме субботы и воскресенья. В четверг магазин открыт с 15 часов.

Вам необходимо добавить час и день недели в качестве ввода.
День недели представлен в виде целого числа (1 для понедельника, 2 для вторника и т. д.)

Пример ввода:
15
4

Пример вывода:
Open

Мой код:

```
    hour = int(input())
    day = int(input())
    if day == 6 or day == 7:
        print('Closed')
    if (hour < 15 or hour > 21) and (day == 4):
        print('Closed')
    if (hour < 10 or hour > 21) and (day == 1 or day == 2 or day == 3 or day == 5):
        print('Closed')
    else:
        print('Open')
```

Проблема:

Если вводить субботу или воскресенье (6 или 7 день) идет двойной вывод: сначала прога возвращает, как и должно быть, Closed и следом за ним почему-то еще и Open.

Тот же результат, если вводить нерабочие часы четверга.

С остальными днями недели все равботает как должно.

Comment: потому что у вас проверяются все условия. почитайте про оператор `elif`/

Comment: спасибо, я уж обчитался. но почитаю еще :)

Comment: print('Open') срабатывает для day равном 6 или 7 и hour от 21 до 10, потому, что else привязан только к третьему условию... замените второй и третий if на elif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас четыре **взаимоисключаемые** условия:

> СБ, ВС - закрыт (однозначно, и дальше нечего проверять)
>
> ЧТ - закрыт, если время меньше 15 или больше 21
>
> остальные дни - закрыт, если время меньше 10 или больше 21
>
> иначе (если ничего из вышеперечисленного не сработало) - открыт

Вот для такого взаимоисключения elif и нужен (из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if)):

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" assignment_expression ":" suite
         ("elif" assignment_expression ":" suite)*
         ["else" ":" suite]
```

Код:

```
hour = int(input())
day = int(input())

if day == 6 or day == 7:
    print('Closed')
elif day == 4 and 15 > hour > 21:
    print('Closed')
elif 10 > hour > 21:
    print('Closed')
else:
    print('Open')
```

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! Я не надеялся получить готовый код, расчитывал только на указание направления, но все равно спасибо всем, кто заморочался и с подсказкой, и с кодом, и с объясениями! Особенно понравилось объяснение, как сократить код (правда, я не все понял).

Answer (score 2):

судя по примеру ввода - данные надо вводить в 1 строке, тогда

```
hour, day = map(int, input().split())
```

а дальше можно отталкивать только от времени работы магазина:

```
if 1 <= day < 4 and 10 <= hour <= 21:
    print("open")
elif day == 4 and 15 <= hour <= 21:
    print("open")
else:
    print("closed")
```

можно подсвернуть:

```
if (1 <= day < 4 and 10 <= hour <= 21) or (day == 4 and 15 <= hour <= 21):
    print("open")
else:
    print("closed")
```

или еще подсвернуть:

```
print("open" if (1 <= day < 4 and 10 <= hour <= 21) or (day == 4 and 15 <= hour <= 21) else "closed")
```

или еще подсвернуть:

```
print(("closed", "open")[(1 <= day < 4 and 10 <= hour <= 21) or (day == 4 and 15 <= hour <= 21)])
```

Comment: на втором "или еще подсвернуть" я подвис )) ушел разбираться, как это работает...

Comment: второй - это тернарный оператор `результат if условие else другой_результат`, а третий - это использование того, что False/True - это при переводе в целые числа преобразуется в `0/1`, поэтому создаем массив (список или кортеж) ответов для `False` и `True` - `(результат для False, результат для True)` и потом обращаемся к нужной ячейке через `[условие]`, которое будет преобразовано в `[0]` или `[1]`

Answer (score 0):

`else` привязывается к ближайшему `elif`, если такого нет, то к ближайшему `if`.

Что это значит?
Вы вводите `day` как `6`. Пробуем попасть в первое условие. Тут говорится, если день равен 6, то выводится `Closed`, отлично, вроде все как надо, идем дальше.

5 строчка проверяет условие, что у нас не 4 день, первое условие на этой строке нам не интересно, так как второе уже не сработало. В результате, так как день не равен 4, то пропускаем и идем дальше.

7 строчка тоже не срабатывает, так как у нас ни один из тех дней, что на этой строчке перечислены.

9 строчка. Она привязана к ближайшему `if`, то есть к 7 строке. 7 строка уже выдала `false`, она не сработала, а раз она не сработала то как раз данный `else` сработает в любом случае.
То есть у вас выполнится и условие на 3 строке и `else`.

Если же вы хотите, чтобы `else` сработал не из-за последнего if, то их надо связать.

```
    hour = int(input())
    day = int(input())
    if day == 6 or day == 7:
        print('Closed')
    elif (hour < 15 or hour > 21) and (day == 4):
        print('Closed')
    elif (hour < 10 or hour > 21) and (day == 1 or day == 2 or day == 3 or day == 5):
        print('Closed')
    else:
        print('Open')
```

Теперь условие `elif (hour < 15 or hour > 21) and (day == 4):` может выполниться только если не сработает `if day == 6 or day == 7:`.

Условие `elif (hour < 10 or hour > 21) and (day == 1 or day == 2 or day == 3 or day == 5):` только если не сработают два предыдущих.

И в результате `else` сработает только если не сработают все предыдущие. А у вас оно бы сработало, только если не выполнится `elif (hour < 10 or hour > 21) and (day == 1 or day == 2 or day == 3 or day == 5):`.

А вообще рекомендую свой код запустить [здесь](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), чтобы вы смогли построчно пройтись по вашему коду, чтобы лучше понять, как это работает

P.S. другие комментаторы уже приложили такой код, так что мой комментарий имеет смысл только в подробном описании вашего примера

Answer (score -2):

я тоже решал эту задачу, при чем здорово так споткнулся о неё. У меня концепция решения вся True (вначале указываем основное условие) if, а затем баним ненужные нам ветвления в elif. По-моему довольно изящно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]